# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Hint 'noexpand' on object 'View_CMS_Tree_Joined' is invalid

Tags: kentico

I upgraded Kentico from version 8.2 to 9.0. Now getting the following error.

```
Hint 'noexpand' on object 'View_CMS_Tree_Joined' is invalid.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Hint 'noexpand' on object 'View_CMS_Tree_Joined' is invalid.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[SqlException (0x80131904): Hint 'noexpand' on object 'View_CMS_Tree_Joined' is invalid.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +392
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +815
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +4515
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData() +61
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() +138
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +6738869
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds) +6741487
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) +586
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) +107
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) +288
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +180
   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +21
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +325
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +420
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet) +278
   CMS.DataEngine.AbstractDataConnection.ExecuteQuery(String queryText, QueryDataParameters queryParams, QueryTypeEnum queryType, Boolean requiresTransaction) +261

[Exception: 
[DataConnection.HandleError]: 

Query: 
SELECT [NodeAliasPath], [DocumentURLPath], [NodeID], [DocumentCulture]
FROM View_CMS_Tree_Joined AS V WITH (NOLOCK, NOEXPAND) LEFT OUTER JOIN COM_SKU AS S WITH (NOLOCK) ON V.NodeSKUID = S.SKUID
WHERE (NodeSiteID = 1) AND ([DocumentURLPath] LIKE @DocumentURLPath OR [DocumentURLPath] LIKE @DocumentURLPath1)

Caused exception: 
Hint 'noexpand' on object 'View_CMS_Tree_Joined' is invalid.
]
   CMS.DataEngine.AbstractDataConnection.HandleError(String queryText, Exception ex) +181
   CMS.DataEngine.AbstractDataConnection.ExecuteQuery(String queryText, QueryDataParameters queryParams, QueryTypeEnum queryType, Boolean requiresTransaction) +776
   CMS.DataEngine.GeneralConnection.RunQuery(QueryParameters query) +383
   CMS.DataEngine.GeneralConnection.ExecuteQuery(QueryParameters query) +401
   CMS.DataEngine.GeneralConnection.ExecuteQuery(QueryParameters query, Int32& totalRecords) +75
   CMS.DataEngine.DataQueryBase`1.GetDataFromDBInternal() +143
   CMS.DataEngine.DataQueryBase`1.GetDataFromDB() +96
   CMS.DataEngine.DataQueryBase`1.GetData() +149
   CMS.DataEngine.DataQueryBase`1.get_Result() +114
   CMS.DataEngine.ObjectQueryBase`2.GetResults(IDataQuery query, Int32& totalRecords) +41
   CMS.DataEngine.DataQueryBase`1.GetDataFromDB() +128
   CMS.DocumentEngine.DocumentQueryBase`2.<GetDataFromDB>b__2() +9
   CMS.DocumentEngine.DocumentQueryProperties.GetDataInternal(IDocumentQuery query, Func`1 baseGetDataMethod, Action`1 setTotalRecords) +91
   CMS.DataEngine.DataQueryBase`1.GetData() +149
   CMS.DataEngine.ObjectQueryBase`2.GetData() +273
   CMS.DocumentEngine.DocumentQueryBase`2.GetData() +171
   CMS.DataEngine.DataQueryBase`1.get_Result() +114
   CMS.DataEngine.DataQueryBase`1.GetResults(IDataQuery query, Int32& totalRecords) +32
   CMS.DataEngine.DataQueryBase`1.GetDataFromDB() +128
   CMS.DocumentEngine.MultiDocumentQueryBase`3.<GetDataFromDB>b__2() +9
   CMS.DocumentEngine.DocumentQueryProperties.GetDataInternal(IDocumentQuery query, Func`1 baseGetDataMethod, Action`1 setTotalRecords) +91
   CMS.DataEngine.DataQueryBase`1.GetData() +149
   CMS.DataEngine.DataQueryBase`1.get_Result() +114
   CMS.URLRewritingEngine.CMSDocumentRouteHelper.RegisterDocumentRoutes(String where, String siteName, List`1 routes) +525
   CMS.URLRewritingEngine.CMSDocumentRouteHelper.RegisterRoutes(String siteName) +206
   CMS.URLRewritingEngine.CMSDocumentRouteHelper.EnsureRoutes(String siteName) +252
   CMS.URLRewritingEngine.URLRewritingHandlers.AuthorizeRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) +271
   CMS.Base.AbstractHandler.CallEventHandler(EventHandler`1 h, TArgs e) +117
   CMS.Base.AbstractHandler.Raise(String partName, List`1 list, TArgs e, Boolean important) +826
   CMS.Base.SimpleHandler`2.RaiseExecute(TArgs e) +142
   CMS.Base.SimpleHandler`2.RaiseExecute(TArgs e) +214
   CMS.Base.SimpleHandler`2.StartEvent(TArgs e) +300
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +92
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +165
```

Answer (score 1):

In Kentico 9 View_CMS_Tree_Joined is indexed, but in Kentico 8, it isn't. So you need to check that this view has indexes. If not, try no create them:

```
SET ARITHABORT ON
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF

GO

/****** Object:  Index IX_View_CMS_Tree_Joined_ClassName_NodeSiteID_DocumentForeignKeyValue_DocumentCulture] ******/

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_View_CMS_Tree_Joined_ClassName_NodeSiteID_DocumentForeignKeyValue_DocumentCulture] ON [dbo].[View_CMS_Tree_Joined]
(
[ClassName] ASC,
[NodeSiteID] ASC,
[DocumentForeignKeyValue] ASC,
[DocumentCulture] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_View_CMS_Tree_Joined_NodeSiteID_DocumentCulture_NodeID] ON [dbo].[View_CMS_Tree_Joined]
(
[NodeSiteID] ASC,
[DocumentCulture] ASC,
[NodeID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```